# Modular arithmetic with powers and prime numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have been struggling with this problem for a long time.

$$
19^9 \mod 1189 = 1113\\
29^9 \mod 1189 = 522\\
39^9 \mod 1189 = 308\\
x^9 \mod 1189 = 377
$$

the answer is $87$. It can be easily found by factorization (the fact that $1189=29 \times 41$ and then we can use [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)). However, I would like to find the answer by hand. Is it possible?

Interesting fact is $19 + 29 + 39 = 87$ which is the answer, and $1113 + 522 + 308 = 754$ which is $377\times 2$.

I summed up all the equations and have the following:

$$m^9 = 1189k + 377$$

And from here, I cannot get to anywhere else.

Comment: With "can be easily found by factorization", you're referring to $1189 = 29\cdot 41$ and the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer Exactly. Forgot to mention.